# How can my application get online data?

Tags: windows-phone-8, database-connection

My friend said that the application can download the HTML file in a website and get helpful data for the application. But it's in Android. So can we make the same thing in window phone?
For example, my website has a table. Can my application get that table then save it's data?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can build an app that can download a webpage in the background? If si then use the httpclient object.

If you want to display a webpage in your app there is a browser control you can use.

Comment: Thank you! I know web browser control in wp8. OK, I'll find httpclient object.